# Angular 8 to Angular 9 Migration

Tags: angular9

After a successful upgrade of a library from *Angular 8* to *Angular 9*
when I try to build it I get the following error:

```
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: Decorator argument must resolve to a string
An unhandled exception occurred: Decorator argument must resolve to a string
```

any lead on what can cause this error or what does it mean?

Comment: Did you check your typescript version ? It should be 3.6 or 3.7

Comment: Please share your package.json `dependencies` and `devDependencies`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues happened because some of the components Output property had a name which was an Enum and not a plain string. once I changed all those places to a string, it solved the issue.